# Significant model but not the predictors? (Logistic regression)

Tags: logistic, spss

I'm doing a binary regression, with two predictors one binary and one continuous. I'm using the enter method.

I want to know if my model can be significant when I compare it to the model with only the constant while at the same time all my predictors are not significant?

Or there something wrong about my model?

Comment: "Enter" is not a method and it certainly has problems with bias, invalidating standard errors P-values, and confidence limits.